# web application working build in flask not stable on app engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, google-app-engine

i had uploaded an python flask app on app engine and where i used session in it for after login pages, and app is perfectly working fine on my local computer, and their is no bug in it , but my app works different on app engine,  when i saw logs then i realize app engine automatically clearing session cookies at any point i don't know why it is happing because app is perfectly working fine on my local computer, and when app engine clearing my session then program redirect me to login page, which is necessary if session is clear according to my login_required decorator
so please give me the solution of this app engine bug

decorator function:-

def login_required(f):
@wraps(f)
def deco_function(*args, **kwargs):
print("hii")
print(session)
if 'loggedin' in session:
return f(*args, **kwargs)
return redirect(url_for('login'))
return deco_function

login route:-

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if bcrypt.checkpw(request.form['password'].encode('utf-8'), hashed_pass.encode('utf-8')) and (request.form['user_name'] == firebase_user_name) :
       session['loggedin'] = 'admin'
       print(session)
       return redirect(url_for('dashboard'))
    flash('Username or password incorrect')
return render_template('login.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

What does `session['loggedin'] = 'admin'` actually do? Is that setting cookies somehow?

I'm running flask and i call this `set_session_cookie` function in my login handler:

```
from werkzeug.http import dump_cookie

def set_session_cookie(response, cookies_value, max_age=DEFAULT_MAX_AGE):
    cookie = dump_cookie(
        'my_cookies_name',
        cookies_value,
        max_age=max_age,
        secure=True,
    )
    response.headers.add('Set-Cookie', cookie)
```

and then in my `login_required` decorator i do `request.cookies.get('my_cookies_name', None)` to retrieve `cookies_value` and I then validate `cookies_value`

Comment: thanks for the help brother, and yes session['loggedin']  = 'admin' setting a cookie session , and a good news is i found the problem , bug is in my secret_key where i used os.unrandom(26) library for creating secret key which is creating problem on app engine, so instead of using os library i use a random string which solved my bug instantly.